# Why is Random() not behaving as expected?

Tags: java, random

I've been scratching my head over this for long enough, It's time for the big guns:

```
System.out.println(new Random(10).nextInt());
```

why does the above seem to print `-1157793070`, always?

Comment: Did you want to generate a random number between 0 and 10 or something like that? [See the many answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363681/5133585).

Comment: No, I was just playing around with Random, and noticed this peculiarity.

Comment: It is not a peculiarity, nor is it misbehaving, it is intentional and well-known behaviour of pseudo-random generators like `Random`, and it is even explicitly called out in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html): _"If two instances of `Random` are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers."_

Comment: ...but, yes, during my play time, I was attempting to get a random number between 0 and 10. For shame!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you define a custom `seed` that is always the same with each run. From the JavaDoc:

> The seed is the initial value of the internal state of the pseudorandom
> number generator which is maintained by method {@link #next}.

This is particularly useful for running tests.